# C++ - how to mock functions from different class, different headers?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have one module which contain headers say h1, h2, h3 and cpp1 cpp2, cpp3.   I am writing unit test function for function in cpp3 file say Foo();.
The Foo() function  calls

- Function F1() from cpp1 - definition and declaration in header h1 whose classname is "class1".
- Function F2() from cpp2 - definition and declaration in header h2 whose classname is "class2".

If I have another module for unit test creation where I am writing code in ".cc" file.

---

So my questions are:

1. How can I define the mock class for both function F1 and F2 in one mock file, as I assume my module should have only one mock file?
2. Do I need to create mock class for both class1 and class2 in one mock file?
3. How can I then use that in my ".cc" file for unit test code implementation?

Answer (score 0):

1. You certainly *can* define all your mocks in one file, but I think that it's more common to define mocks in separate headers. For example, if you have a class Foo then you'd have a separate file, MockFoo.h which defines the mock object.
2. As above, you can create mocks for class1 and class2 in the same file, or in separate files.
3. In your unit test file, you simply need to include the relevant headers for your mock objects. If you have a single file with all of your mocks, you'd just need to #include that file, and if you have multiple files (i.e. MockClass1.h, MockClass2.h) you'll just need to #include all of them.

Comment: Thanks for you answers!!  I pretty much clear  now.

Some more queries : 
Both base and derived class declaratio in same header file say H1.h.
class Base 
{
   bool INLINEBASE1(){return true;}   
   bool INLINEBASE2() {return false;}
}
class derived : public Base
{
   FOO()
   {
    if (INLINEBASE1()  && INLINEBASE2())
      ....
    }
}

Have some question like :
1.  If I am writing a unit test for a function say FOO() from derived class.  Cpp1.cpp file.
But FOO() function have some inline function call from Base class.  
Then how can I mock inline base class functions?